# javascript quiz : Display random options

Tags: javascript, html

I just coded a html quiz page... Here is My Javascript Code

```
 <SCRIPT language="JavaScript"    type="text/javascript">

function checkAnswer(quizForm,
                     theAnswer,
                     ){
  var s = "?";  
  var i = 0;
  for(;i<quizForm.elements.length;i++)
  {    if(("cc" ==
        quizForm.elements[i].name) &&
       (quizForm.elements[i].checked))    {
      s = quizForm.elements[i].value;    }  }
  if("?" == s)
  {   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please Click Answer";
    return false;  }

  if(s == theAnswer)
  {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Very Good";   
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please Check Ur Answer";  
  }

  return false;
}

</SCRIPT>
```

and my html code is

```
What is JavaScript?

<FORM method="POST"
      onSubmit="return checkAnswer(this,'B');"
>

<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" VALUE="A" NAME="cc">
A. Another name for Java<BR>

<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" VALUE="B" NAME="cc">
B. A scripting language mostly for the web<BR>

<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" VALUE="C" NAME="cc">
C. When you use Java without compiling<BR>

<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit Answer">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want to add my options (A,B,C,D) in Javascript code. which can randomly display options and also when user click right answer it shows '`Correct` else `Wrong`

Answer (score 0):

To randomize the question, you need to store your question in an array or object. Then, when you show the question, you just need to show the randomized version of the question:

```
let questions = [
  {
    questions: ["Options 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "option 4"],
    answer: "Option 2", 
  },
]

let randomizeArray = (arr) =>{
  let Question = [],
      till = arr.length; 
  while(Question.length != till){
    if(arr.length === 1){
      Question[Question.length] = arr.splice(0, 1)[0];
    }else{
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(arr.length));
      Question[Question.length] = arr.splice(random, 1)[0];
    }
  }
  return Question;
}
```

Here, `randomizeArray` alawys return the randomize array. 
You need to show user the randomized version of the question.

Then, when user selects an answer, you need to compare it with the answer. And show user the associative answer.

I think you get the idea.

Comment: It little bit confused me. Where do call this `randomizeArray` ?

Comment: the `randomizeArray` function return randomize array.. It just allow you make your question randomize.. you can call this function in your html template generator function